# Java return datatype when class is stored in an array

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

This is my sample class

```java
public class Value<E> {
    public final E value;

    public Value(E value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And this returns a String and no Object, so I don't need to cast it.

```
String a = new Value<String>("test").value;
```

However, if I want to do this, then I need to cast it.

```
ArrayList<Value<?>> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new Value<String>("test"));

String b = a.get(0).value; // Runtime error
```

If I add the value to the `ArrayList` it returns an `Object`, but I want it to return what I defined the Element to be.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You defined that you don't know (or care) what types are contained inside with `Value<?>`, so you can only treat them as `Object` as that's the one thing they're guaranteed to be (they can also be subclasses, but they'll still always be `Object`s too).

If you think and hope you can store `String`s and `Integer`s in the same `List`, that's not possible except by treating them as `Objects`. Besides, you shouldn't be storing different types (except through inheritance hierarchy) in the same collection anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
ArrayList<Value<?>> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

with

```
ArrayList<Value<String>> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: The point is, that I also want the value to be an Integer and store the datatype within the object ```Value```

Comment: And how should the compiler be aware that the first value object you add contains an Integer and the second one a String? That is not possible.

Comment: Well, I thought it would be able to return the correct datatype because of the
```public final E value;```

I guess then I need to use instanceof and then cast it, if it's not possible.
Thank you.